# I'm trying to remove all the noise - I only want a list of urls

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping

I'm trying to parse a list of URLs seen below. text.strip() doesn't seem to work for me and I am unsure why. I have all the data there but to drill into each link I need a clean list of URLs only. I just want a list that begins with ['https://lakesshoweringspaces.com/catalogue_product/alassio/?', .....] and continues through each link.

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
    
    s = HTMLSession()
    def get_product_links(page):
      url = f'https://lakesshoweringspaces.com/catalogue-product-filter/page/{page}'
      links = []
      r = s.get(url)
    
      products = r.html.find("article.contentwrapper section.collection-wrapper-item")
    
      for item in products:
          res = links.append(item.find("a", first=True))
          if res:
              (res.attrs["href"])
          else:
              ("")
      return links
    
    page1 = get_product_links(1)
    print(page1)
```

I think I have been clear in what I am trying to do and apologies if I have not. This is a sample of what prints:

[<Element 'a' href='https://lakesshoweringspaces.com/catalogue_product/alassio/?' rel=('bookmark',) title='Alassio'>, <Element 'a' href='https://lakesshoweringspaces.com/catalogue_product/amare/?' rel=('bookmark',) t.......]
Can anyone help me here?

Comment: `(res.attrs["href"])` does nothing though? What do you expect this line to do? Did you mean to write `res = res.attrs["href"]`. Also `ref` is just `None` since you write `res = links.append(item.find("a", first=True))` (`append` returns `None`)

Comment: got it sorted. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

s = HTMLSession()
def get_product_links(page):
  url = f'https://lakesshoweringspaces.com/catalogue-product-filter/page/{page}'
  links = []
  r = s.get(url)

  products = r.html.find("article.contentwrapper section.collection-wrapper-item")

  for item in products:
    links.append(item.find("a", first=True).attrs['href'])
  return links

page1 = get_product_links(1)
print(page1)enter code here
```

Comment: Could you explain what the problem with OPs code was and how exactly this fixes it rather than just posting a snippet.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).